# Top drop block for Drupal?

Tags: php, jquery, drupal

If you go to this page:

```
https://www.udemy.com/blog/modern-language-wars/
```

You will see a block drop from the top. (i'm a poet and didn't know it).

1. What do you call this drop down? What would you search for if you wanted a plugin like this?
2. What is the best plugin in DRUPAL that I could use to get this effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need a plugin to produce this effect.  It can be done with a simple [jQuery slideToggle](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/).  I made a quick mock-up in jsfiddle for you here: http://jsfiddle.net/nDMuJ/.  I used a click event for the sake of a quick example, but you can bind it to any myriad of events (ie scroll).

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="slider">
        SLIDER CONTENT
    </div>
    PAGE CONTENT
</div>
<div class="button">CLICK ME TO SLIDE</div>
```

JS:

```
$(".button").click(function(){
    $(".slider").slideToggle();
});
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
}

.slider {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
}
```